# In ag-grid, is it possible to select multiple rows with checkboxes and also highlight row by clicking (should not select the checkbox of the row)?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

We have a requirement to distinguish between row click and checkbox selection in ag-grid.
Row selection we are doing with checkboxes with property `rowSelection={'multiple'}`

Row click should highlight the row with blue color background. This we tried using rowstyles but cannot able to achieve it. Can someone suggest on this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should

1. Set rowSelection to "single". Thereby you support required behavior for click.
2. Use [cellRenderer](https://ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/cell-rendering/) column property to implement you own realization for multi selection via checkboxes without row selection in terms of ag grid (store checkbox state outside of grid).